# Open and closed set in n by n matrices space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

This problem seems to be easy yet I have no idea to deal with.

If $\mathbb{M} ^n$ is the set of all real square matrices of order n, identified here with $\mathbb{R} ^{n^2}$ equipped with its usual Euclidean norm which induce an usual topology on the space $\mathbb{M}^n$. Show that:

1. The set of all invertible real matrices of order n is open in $\mathbb{M} ^n$ with respect to the Euclidean norm topology;
2. The set $\mathbb{S} ^n$ which consists of all real symmetric matrices of order n is closed in $\mathbb{M} ^n$ with respect to the Euclidean norm topology.

For question #1, by the hint which is given by @Brent Kerby, that $det:\mathbb{M}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Comment: Hint for (1): Use the fact that the determinant, being a polynomial in several variables, is continuous.

Comment: As you have mentioned that the Determinant is a continuous mapping from $\mathbb{M}^n$ onto $\mathbb{R}$. How about the Trace mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint:**

1. There is a standard continuous map $f:\, \mathbb{M}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and a closed set $C \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that the set of invertible $n \times n$ matrices is equal to the complement of $f^{-1}(C)$ in $\mathbb{M}^n$.  Hence $\mathrm{GL}_n( \mathbb{R} )$ is open.
2. Observe that $$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{pmatrix}$$ is symmetric if and only if $b = c$.  This implies that the symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices are the fiber of a continuous map $\mathbb{M}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Generalize appropriately.

Comment: What does it mean that " the"symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices are the fiber of a continusous map" here?

Comment: A fiber of a continuous map is the preimage of a singleton set in the codomain. This idea applies to the first part of your problem as well.